# How to disable 'Sticky Scroll' in Visual Studio 2022 preview?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 v17.6.0 preview 4.0, and I would like to get rid of this horrible pane in the top of the text editor.

I consider it of no help, it only serves to distract me because it is constantly changing its height (adding/removing lines) while scrolling the text editor, and thus it is constantly changing the position of the text search popup. It only serves to reduce the visible space of the text editor...

[image]

I call it "code hierarchy tracking top pane" because I don't know the official name of this feature.

I can't find this feature in the settings nor in the preview features that can be disabled within the Visual Studio settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it. The feature it is called "Sticky Scroll" and it can be found in general settings:

[image]

I also found an easier way to disable it, just by pressing right mouse button in a empty space at the left of the line numbers:

[image]

Sources of interest:

- https://dev.to/bytehide/visual-studio-codes-new-editor-sticky-scroll-feature-never-get-lost-in-the-code-again-1dob
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/sticky-scroll-now-in-preview/

Comment: Thank you! That thing was driving me crazy!

Comment: Thank you! Arguably one of the worst VSCode features.